# FAFSA implications of filing jointly?

Tags: united-states, taxes, accounting, fafsa

Recently our accountant filed a tax return as **married** for my partner and me (we live together). She is applying for FAFSA and is not sure whether she should be reflecting her marital status from our tax return. Our accountant explained that since we share an asset (home), our state basically considers us in a civil union. However, if she files FAFSA *single*, she's being asked for the adjusted gross income of our combined fax return. Would it be beneficial to amend our tax return so that she would be more eligible for FAFSA aid?

Comment: owning a house = married? What state is it?

Comment: @littleadv Illinois. House is under both our names.

Comment: According to this link, there's no "common law" marriage in Illinois... http://www.illinoislegalaid.org/index.cfm?fuseaction=home.dsp_content&contentID=2447

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it would be worth it for you to get a second opinion from a different accountant.  Hopefully that second opinion will correctly determine whether or not filing as married was the correct thing.  If Illinois doesn't have common law marriage or civil unions, your first accountant may have erred in having you file as married.

I don't know if you can (or should) submit multiple federal forms with different marital statuses.